# Java 8 migration with internal dependencies

Tags: jar, dependencies, java-8

My project which is a war depends on two other jars. One of the jars is migrated to java 8. The other one isn't.

Can I migrate the war to Java 8. I am seeing some auto wiring issues from the jar that's not migrated.

Anyone ideas or inputs?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Java 8 works fine with "old" code. What are the auto wiring issues that you are seeing?